# How can I remove all objects but one from the workspace in R?

Tags: r

I have a workspace with lots of objects and I would like to remove all but one.  Ideally I would like to avoid having to type `rm(obj.1, obj.2... obj.n)`.  Is it possible to indicate  `remove all objects but these ones`?

Answer (score 504, accepted):

Here is a simple construct that will do it, by using `setdiff`:

```
rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "x"))
```

And a full example.  Run this at your own risk - it will remove all variables except `x`:

```
x <- 1
y <- 2
z <- 3
ls()
[1] "x" "y" "z"

rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "x"))

ls()
[1] "x"
```

Comment: The technique being used here is to use list= to rm, which allows a character vector to be passed to rm instead of a list of names.

Comment: So if one wants to keep several files it would be `rm(list=setdiff(ls(), c("x", "x2")))`

Answer (score 75):

Using the `keep` function from the `gdata` package is quite convenient.

```
> ls()
[1] "a" "b" "c"

library(gdata)
> keep(a) #shows you which variables will be removed
[1] "b" "c"
> keep(a, sure = TRUE) # setting sure to TRUE removes variables b and c
> ls()
[1] "a"
```

Comment: I find that using "keep" from gdata seems to make more sense and it's easier to remember that all the complexity of the comand in base R.

Comment: Can we add this please as base r function?

Answer (score 74):

I think **another option** is to open workspace in RStudio and then change list to grid at the top right of the environment(image below). Then tick the objects you want to clear and finally click on clear.

[image]

Comment: Likewise, click the Name box, which selects all the files, and then deselect all the files you want to keep.

Answer (score 56):

I just spent several hours hunting for the answer to a similar but slightly different question - I needed to be able to delete all objects in R (including functions) except a handful of vectors.

One way to do this:

```
rm(list=ls()[! ls() %in% c("a","c")])
```

Where the vectors that I want to keep are named 'a' and 'c'.

Hope this helps anyone searching for the same solution!

Comment: This should also work, `rm(list=setdiff(ls(), c("a", "c")))`, right? See @Andrie's answer.

Answer (score 21):

To keep all objects whose names match a pattern, you could use `grep`, like so:

```
to.remove <- ls()
to.remove <- c(to.remove[!grepl("^obj", to.remove)], "to.remove")
rm(list=to.remove)
```

Comment: Amazing! Do you know any way to make this answer a one-line code instead of three?

Comment: @Luis 
rm(list=grep("^obj", ls(), value=T, invert=T))

Answer (score 21):

Replace `v` with the name of the object you want to keep

```
rm(list=(ls()[ls()!="v"]))
```

hat-tip: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Removing-objects-and-clearing-memory-tp3445763p3445865.html

Answer (score 19):

To keep a **list** of objects, one can use:

```
rm(list=setdiff(ls(), c("df1", "df2")))
```

Answer (score 6):

This takes advantage of `ls()`'s `pattern` option, in the case you have a lot of objects with the same pattern that you don't want to keep:

```
> foo1 <- "junk"; foo2 <- "rubbish"; foo3 <- "trash"; x <- "gold"  
> ls()
[1] "foo1" "foo2" "foo3" "x"   
> # Let's check first what we want to remove
> ls(pattern = "foo")
[1] "foo1" "foo2" "foo3"
> rm(list = ls(pattern = "foo"))
> ls()
[1] "x"
```

Comment: whoah, that seems dangerous! Is there a way to test the pattern matching a la "echo" in the shell?

Comment: I guess the `rm` function should always be used with care (more so in the shell!). See my edit for an answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

```
require(gdata)
keep(object_1,...,object_n,sure=TRUE)
ls()
```

Comment: Duplicate of @Rahul Premraj's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7205040/2563804).

Answer (score 3):

From within a function, rm all objects in .GlobalEnv except the function

```
initialize <- function(country.name) {

  if (length(setdiff(ls(pos = .GlobalEnv), "initialize")) > 0) {
    rm(list=setdiff(ls(pos = .GlobalEnv), "initialize"), pos = .GlobalEnv)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

let's think in different way, what if we wanna remove a group?
try this,

```
 rm(list=ls()[grep("xxx",ls())])
```

I personally don't like too many tables, variables on my screen, yet I can't avoid using them. So I name the temporary things starting with "xxx", so I can remove them after it is no longer used.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you want to remove every object except df from environment:

```
rm(list = ls(pattern="[^df]"))
```

Comment: This is not correct. `[^df]` is the negation of a *set* of characters `d` and `f`. This will also remove `fdd` and `fd` and `ddd` for instance, and keep any object that has at least one instance of a character that is not `d` or `f`.

Answer (score 2):

```
# remove all objects but selected
rm(list = ls()[which("key_function" != ls())])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
# Removes all objects except the specified & the function itself.

rme <- function(except=NULL){
  except = ifelse(is.character(except), except, deparse(substitute(except)))
  rm(list=setdiff(ls(envir=.GlobalEnv), c(except,"rme")), envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```