# Regex in R: match everything but not "some string"

Tags: regex, r

The answers to another question explain [how to match a string not containing a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word).

The problem (for me) is that the solutions given don't work in R.

Often I create a `data.frame()` from existing vectors and want to clean up my workspace. So for example, if my workspace contains:

```
> ls()
[1] "A"   "B"   "dat" "V"
>
```

and I want to retain only `dat`, I'd have to clean it up with:

```
> rm(list=ls(pattern="A"))
> rm(list=ls(pattern="B"))
> rm(list=ls(pattern="V"))
> ls()
[1] "dat"
>
```

(where `A`, `B`, and `V` are just examples of a large number of complicated names like `my.first.vector` that are not easy to match with `rm(list=ls(pattern="[ABV]"))`).

It would be most convenient (for me) to tell `rm()` to remove everything except `dat`, but the problem is that the solution given in the linked Q&A does not work:

```
> rm(list=ls(pattern="^((?!dat).)*$"))
Error in grep(pattern, all.names, value = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression '^((?!dat).)*$', reason 'Invalid regexp'
>
```

So how *can* I match everything except `dat` in R?

Comment: Did you try `rm(list=ls()[ls()!="dat"])`?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Thank you! I did not think of indexing the object returned by `ls()`.

Comment: duplicate of [How can I remove all objects but one from the workspace in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6190051/1036500)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will remove all objects except `dat` .  (Use the `ls` argument `all.names = TRUE` if you want to remove objects whose names begin with a dot as well.)

```
rm( list = setdiff( ls(), "dat" ) )
```

Replace `"dat"` with a vector of names, e.g. `c("dat", "some.other.object")`, if you want to retain several objects; or, if the several objects can all be readily matched by a regular expression try something like this which removes all objects whose names do not start with `"dat"`:

```
rm( list = setdiff( ls(), ls( pattern = "^dat" ) ) )
```

Another approach is to save the data, `save("dat", file = "dat.RData")`, exit R, start a new R session and load the data, `1oad("dat.RData")`.   Also note [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313079/quit-and-restart-a-clean-r-session-from-within-r/6315855#6315855) of restarting R.

Comment: I would not want to exit R just to clear my work space.

Comment: @what, Personally, I try not to use `rm` and prefer to start a clean R session.   If you write your software in a reproducible manner then its just a matter of rerunning your script.

Comment: Yes, but some of my scripts load a lot of data (from an URL or from an Excel Workbook), or write a lot of files, and execution takes a couple of seconds. Also, I love the flexibility that your solution of adding a vector gives, because it allows me to delete everything left over from the creation of my `data.frame()` *and* keeping everything else I have kept up to that point, and those "leftovers" would be lost after exiting R, or I would have to save them also, which might make the whole process a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 4):

`Negative look-around` requires `perl=TRUE` argument in R. So, you won't be able to directly use `ls(pattern = ...)` with that regular expression. Alternatively you can do:

```
rm(list = grep("^((?!dat).)*$", ls(), perl=TRUE, value=TRUE))
```

This is if you're looking for inexact matches. If you're looking for exact match, you should just do what Ferdinand has commented:

```
rm(list=ls()[ls() != "dat"])
```

Comment: First sentence seems to be ignoring the fact that the R `grep` function has an invert parameter: `rm(list=grep("dat", ls(), value=TRUE, invert=TRUE))`. This would keep any that had "dat" in the name or you could use the "^dat$" pattern if you wanted to be less inclusive. (I would think one would need to be more selective and only remove non-functions.)

Comment: @DWin, very much true. I was just taking his regular expression and showing how to do it in R. I did not put effort in formulating a regexp.