# R - file.remove() by filetype

Tags: r

I am using the following code to remove all generated .json temp files in my project:

```
file.remove(list.files(pattern = ".json"))
```

Is there a more simple way to achieve it without nesting functions?

Comment: with magrittr if you want to use the pipe operator. But your approach is very fine.

Comment: More ideas at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190051/how-can-i-remove-all-objects-but-one-from-the-workspace-in-r